# Entity framework database first not accepting values with 12 decimal places

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

In my DB I have a column defined with decimal (30,12).
I am trying to update the column value with decimals upto 12 places. 
But its giving me error "conversion overflow" when I do dbcontext.save from the entity framework. basically I wanted to support a deciaml with 14 didit at the left and 12 digit in right. (12345678998734.898989898989)

Comment: What is the database you are using? Also, the column should be defined as decimal(26,12).  Depending on the version of the database, the limits for the maximum precision of decimal vary.

Comment: Just in case, Is your dbcontext in sync with the database? It may happen if you have updated the database after updating the edmx

Answer (score 0):

The maximum precision allowed in SQL Server is 38. But SQL Server decimal data type is not mapped to the .Net decimal in it’s whole range. .Net decimal type only maps to SQL Server one in the decimal(29, X) range. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks))

That means that if you have a decimal column that has the precision higher than 29 and no matter the scale, you won’t be able to use the native .Net data type.

Try to use the SqlDecimal type.

[Full rules of SQL type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

Comment: The maximum precision allowed for SQL server is indeed 38, but decimal(30,12) is precision of 30, with a scale of 12.  These values are *not* cumulative.  As such, it should fit in the SQL server range.

Comment: Agree with @Kami. I am using decimal(30,12) precision of 30, with a scale of 12. SO it should easily take decimal values with total length=30 and with 12 decimal places. But in my case it isint.